# Binding with c#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have this class

```
public class Entidad 
{       
        public String Campo { get; set; }       
        public String ValorNuevo { get; set; }      
}
```

And this function

```
foreach(List<Entidad> fila in elementosDetalle)
{

    ListView vistaLista = new ListView();       
    GridView vistaCuadricula = new GridView();
    vistaLista.ItemsSource = fila;

   foreach(Entidad campo in fila)
   {

     GridViewColumn columna = new GridViewColumn() { Width = 50, Header =campo.Campo, DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("ValorNuevo") };
    vistaCuadricula.Columns.Add(columna);                   
    }                   

  vistaLista.View = vistaCuadricula;
  stkPanel.Children.Add(vistaLista);                

}
```

The result is:

[image]

And I made a Collection of this class, I'm doing a Binding into a GridView, but I really need is make a in horizontal way; I tried by adding items but it does not work. Please I really need help.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "make a in horizontal way?" What is a? What code did you try?

Comment: You see in the picture, the data is repeated in each column. I need for example: CodigoE=1 Codigo T=100176, Sucursal=0, Codigo T=V in that way, and only show one row.

Comment: you are adding each item as a column and not a row. Try using GridViewRow instead